# Postgres request GROUP BY that I don't want

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, postgresql

I have this code that I use in PHP and Codeigniter:

***Query 1***

```
return $this->db->query("
    SELECT max(dateandtime) as dateandtime 
    FROM table.dat_access 
    WHERE cardcode = 'w123' 
    ")->row();
```

The result is fine, so I now want to retrive another column (`snapshot`) based on that so I thought I need to do this:

***Query 2***

```
return $this->db->query("
    SELECT snapshot, max(dateandtime) as dateandtime 
    FROM table.dat_access 
    WHERE cardcode = 'w123' 
    ")->row();
```

At this point I get this error:

`ERROR: column "dat_access.snapshot" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

But I don't want to group things up at this point. I just need to retrive the snapshot value of the same query.

What I need is to get `snapshot` for the row with max `dateandtime` and the specified `cardcode`.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT snapshot, max(dateandtime) as dateandtime
    FROM table.dat_access
    WHERE cardcode = 'w123'
    GROUP BY dateandtime LIMIT 1
```

But it gives me the error:

```
Error Number: ERROR: column "dat_access.snapshot" must appear in the GROUP BY
clause or be used in an aggregate function.
LINE 1: SELECT snapshot, max(dateandtime) as dateandtime FROM table...^
SELECT snapshot, max(dateandtime) as dateandtime FROM table.dat_access
WHERE cardcode = 'w123' 

Filename: [...]card_model.php

Line Number: 82
```

Note:
when I retrive the field `dateandtime` of the first query works just fine.

Comment: Thare are `n` records and you are specifying the behavior for aggregation (1 record in your case)for only one field `dateandtime` – how can it decide what record from `snapshot` to choose then?

Comment: Do you want to get `snapshot` for the row with max `dateandtime` ?

Comment: This is a common problem. You can use `DISTINCT ON` instead of `GROUP BY` in some cases; otherwise you'll have to do the `max` in a subquery.

Comment: @CraigRinger I've tried that but it says there is a syntax error. Can you be so kind to write the full query? Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you the maximum "dataandtime" for a single cardcode.

```
select cardcode, max(dateandtime) as dateandtime 
from table.dat_access 
group by cardcode
having cardcode = 'w123';
```

Join on that to get "snapshot". You need to join on both columns--"cardcode" *and* "dateandtime".

```
select t1.cardcode, t1.dateandtime, t1.snapshot
from table.dat_access t1
inner join (select cardcode, max(dateandtime) as dateandtime 
            from table.dat_access 
            group by cardcode
            having cardcode = 'w123') t2
  on t1.cardcode = t2.cardcode
 and t1.dateandtime = t2.dateandtime;
```

If you want to keep Query1 unmodified, you can probably change Query2 to this.

```
return $this->db->query("
    SELECT cardcode, snapshot, dateandtime 
    FROM table.dat_access 
    WHERE cardcode = 'w123'
      and dateandtime = [dateandtime from your first query] 
    ")->row();
```

Depending on your table structure, either of these might return more than one row. It depends on whether the combination of "cardcode" and "dateandtime" are unique in your table.

Answer (score 0):

When you use one of the aggregation functions like `MAX()`, you need to specify which rows are to be included in calculation of that maximum (or other value). Implicitly this is done on all returned rows, so your first query works.

But in the second query, you want one result which provides just 1 row (the `MAX(dateandtime)` one), and one which provides *n* rows (the `snapshot`). So it complains.

You now need to add the `GROUP BY` clause explicitly, to say how the grouping should be made, so the results are correct. It hints that `GROUP BY snapshot` would make sense -- on each result row, you would have `snapshot` and the maximum value of `dateandtime` for it.

If that is not what you want (e.g. you want all `snapshots` in the table and maximum `dateandtime` of all rows), you will need to use some other solution, like two queries or a subquery.

Comment: Ok, yes I need the snapshot for the row with max dateandtime, how is that put together?

Comment: OK, try it like this then: `SELECT snapshot, dateandtime FROM ... ORDER BY dateandtime DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: @Mr.Web It could not give you the same error. It has not grouping at all.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko This is the error WITH group:
ERROR: column "dat_access.snapshot" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

This is without:
ERROR:  column "dat_access.snapshot" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: Do you still have MAX() somewhere in the new query?

Comment: Can you not use the new query suggested by @Yirkha? It doesn't use max/group by. `SELECT snapshot, dateandtime FROM ... ORDER BY dateandtime DESC LIMIT 1`